What's the proper string to provide a Mongo ServerAddress for an Atlas database?
I'm trying to connect my Spring Boot API to a Mongo database in Atlas, and configuring the Client like so:
@Override
    public void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
        builder
                .credential(MongoCredential.createCredential("matt", "mydb", "p@ssw0rd".toCharArray()))
                .applyToClusterSettings(settings -> {
                    settings.hosts(Collections.singletonList(new ServerAddress("ab-cdefg-shard-00-00.hijklmn.mongodb.net", 27017)));
                });
    }

But I absolutely cannot get past these errors:
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.lambda$open$0(SocketStream.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:78)
    ... 4 common frames omitted

Am I using an improper string? That's one of the example strings I found, but others used mongo or mongo-srv. I've used them, but I don't know what changes are (and are not) required to accomodate each string format.
I understand and appreciate this configuration, but all the examples I can find use localhost, and I am trying to work with a live Atlas database. My only problem seems to be the specifics of connection parameters (I think).

Connection refused is usually a network thing.  Check your IP whitelisted in your Atlas cluster, the hostname resolves properly in the client, and the port number is what is being used in Atlas.

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to connect your Spring Boot application with MongoDB Atlas.
You can directly take the URL from the Atlas UI or follow the article which emphasizes on Rest API with Spring Boot and MongoDB.
